# gdb: Is there a performance penalty?

Tags: c, gdb

Is there any performance penalty if I attach gdb to a process? I do not set any breakpoint and I'm only waiting for a segfault.

Thanks

Comment: If you're only waiting for a segfault, have you considered having it make a core dump and then looking at that? https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~learn/debugging/modules/gdb_coredumps/

Comment: It depends. But clearly this is an X-Y problem.  Performance is not likely the issue, so if I say "no there is no performance penalty" I will have answered your question Y,  but you still have the same problem X.  Ask about X directly.   It is possible for example that in the debug environment the segfault simply does not occur because of some nondeterministic or undefined behaviour in your code.  That is your code is the X you should be asking about, not the Y of GDB performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any performance penalty if I attach gdb to a process?

Yes.

There are several aspects which slow down when a debugger is attached. One is thread creation / destruction -- GDB needs to keep track of threads, and the pthread library has hooks which GDB sets up.

Also GDB *always* sets a few internal breakpoints. One of them is on `_dl_debug_state()`, and so `dlopen()` and `dlclose()` become slower as well.

Finally, GDB gets notified by the kernel about any signals the program receives, so any application which handles a lot of signals will run slower.

Comment: Is there any quantitative evaluation? 
 how much slower will it be , 1%,  10% or more?  
and will this affect disappear when  gdb is dettached to a process ?

Comment: @luochen1990 1) It _depends_. A program which does nothing except create and join new threads can see 10x slowdown. 2) Yes, detaching should remove all external effects (the program may detect that was running under debugger and change its behavior, but few programs do that).